# C++ Matrix Class Assignment Operator Overloading: Setting Matrix Values

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I am starting to learn how to overload operator functions. I have a matrix that I overloaded to call with `matrix m(int,int);` rather than `matrix m[int][int]`. I am trying to overload the operator=() function so I can read/write the values of the matrix in my main function. Here's what I'm looking at right now:

matrix class code--

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

matrix::matrix(int r, int c) : row(r), col(c)
{
    try
    {
        if (r == 0 || c == 0)
        {
            throw "Exception: Matrix constructor has 0 size";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    data = new double[r * c];
}

matrix::~matrix()
{
    delete[] data;
}

double &matrix::operator()(int r, int c)
{
    try
    {
        if (r >= row || col <= c)
        {
            throw "Exception: Matrix subscript out of bounds";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return data[col * r + c];
}

double matrix::operator()(int r, int c) const
{
    try
    {
        if (r >= row || col <= c)
        {
            throw "Exception: Constant matrix subscript out of bounds";
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return data[col * r + c];
}

matrix &matrix::operator=(const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> &lst)
{
    auto it = lst.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++, it++)
    {
        std::copy(it->begin(), it->end(), this->mat[i]);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

matrix header file--

```
#pragma once
#include <initializer_list>


class matrix 
{
private:
    int row, col;
    double* data;
    int **mat;
public:
    matrix(int, int);
    double& operator() (int, int);
    double  operator() (int, int) const;
    ~matrix();                            // Destructor
    matrix(const matrix&);                // Copy constructor
    matrix& operator= (const std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>&);    // Assignment operator
};
```

Call to overload in main:

```
int mtrx[3][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}};
matrix x(3, 3);
x = {
    {1, 2, 3},  
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9},
};

std::cout << "Matrix mtrx[1][1] = " << mtrx[1][1]; // should print out "Matrix mtrx[1][1] = 5
std::cout << "Matrix x(1,1) = " << x(1,1); // should print out "Matrix x(1,1) = 5
```

Comment: Seems to [work](https://www.godbolt.org/z/bFjHh6). Are you including `<initializer_list>`?

Comment: Yep, I forgot to include that. It did get rid of the compilation errors, though when running the code, the x= {{...}, {...}, {...}}; isn't changing the values of the matrix x. Here's the example I'm trying to make: [link](https://www.godbolt.org/z/jX7_FM)

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question, not as links. Also, I don't see you printing out the results of the assignment anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code above as per your request.

Comment: I thought adding `initializer_list` got rid of the compilation errors. Then update your question accordingly. Also, where in your code are you testing if `operator=` works?

Comment: Oh, yes, it did. Please see the updated code now. I removed the error part and added the cout statements in main.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Data are memorized in `data`, but you initialize  `mat`. I can't see the relationship between both variables

Comment: As @Damien said, you are writing into `mat` but reading from `data`. They are not even pointers to the same type.